# Why I can not use CardView even I import it into libs?

Tags: android, android-cardview

I just new a project to try the CardView class.I know it need a extra .jar library.So I find the cardview-v7-23.0.1-sources.jar in \sdk\extra...\support\cardview-v7\23.0.1.And I copied it and pasted into my new project --the "libs" directory  and add as library.But I still can not use CardView in Activity,why?

Comment: Are you using `Android Studio` or 'Eclipse'?

Comment: Android Studio..I just want to know why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using androidd studio:

app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
        ...
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
    }
```

or if you are using eclipse must download support library

and finally using it

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView
```

After Edit

```
repositories{

    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
            compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        }
```

and sync project

Comment: I am using android studio,and I know the way you do,to compile ..But I  want to know why put the jar file into the libs doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android studio

First of all Update your sdk to latest version.

Add dependency to you build.gradle file

> `'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'`

Add below code to your xml file.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
dependencies {compile files('libs/yourcardviewjarname.jar')}
```